# c# entity framework sum timespan

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, sum

How can I sum a column in Entity Framework and bind in a label?

```
var result = (from t in db.aktivitaet
                          where t.idrapport == idrapport
                          group t by t.aktotal into d
                         select d).Sum();

            lblsum.Text = Convert.ToString(result.Sum( res => res));
```

Something like this, but if it's possible I wanna do it with .toList() like this:

```
var result = (from t in db.aktivitaet
                          where t.idrapport == idrapport
                         select new
                         {
                             t.aktotal
                         }).ToList();
            double sum = 0;
            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                sum += Convert.ToDouble(item.aktotal);
            }
            lblsum.Text = sum.ToString();
```

But using the second code block I get the error:
`Das Objekt des Typs \"System.TimeSpan\" kann nicht in Typ \"System.IConvertible\" umgewandelt werden.`

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = (from t in db.aktivitaet
                      where t.idrapport == idrapport
                     select new
                     {
                         t.aktotal
                     }).ToList();

var sum = result.Aggregate(TimeSpan.Zero, (total, next) => total.Add(next));

lblsum.Text = sum.ToString();
```

This should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in Convert.ToDouble conversion for a timespan object.

Try this:

```
        var result = (from t in db.aktivitaet
                      where t.idrapport == idrapport
                     select new
                     {
                         t.aktotal
                     }).ToList();
        double sum = 0;
        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            sum += item.aktotal.HasValue ? item.aktotal.TotalSeconds : 0;
        }
        lblsum.Text = sum.ToString();
```

Note that the only difference is

```
sum += item.aktotal.HasValue ? item.aktotal.TotalSeconds : 0;
```

It doesn't know what to use as the representation of the timespan without providing the unit of measure (in this case seconds) - you could use TotalHours, TotalMilliseconds, TotalDay, etc - you just have to specify the unit of time that you would like the timespan to be represented as.

Comment: If I try this with TotalSeconds there comes an error 'System.Nullable<System.TimeSpan>' no definition for 'TotalSeconds'

Comment: Sorry I had a syntax error in response, have updated it.  Note that the sum+= is now taking into account if values are null.

Comment: I had anyway problem with your answer because there is no deifnition for TotalSeconds is it easier when I would make a String example: from(00:01:00) + until(00:01:00) = String(2)